# How to remove realm file in case of missing encryption key

Tags: android, encryption, realm

I'm using the unique id from an android device as the encryption key to generate RealmConfiguration.

I found an issue that the unique id changes after app was factory reset or rooted or otherwise.

That means the encryption key is not the same and when I regenerate the RealmConfiguration with new encryption key and try to get the Realm instance, then I got the error "**Illegal Argument: Invalid format of Realm file.**"

I don't want to store the unique id as persistent in app or server. Because it would require more logic to handle a different unique id. So I want to delete Realm file to clear state and using current new encryption key.

But in Realm current version (0.85.1), I found that the *deleteRealm* method is required RealmConfiguration.

**How to remove realm file in case of a missing encryption key, or is the only way to store the encryption key?**

Answer (score 0):

A Realm file is just a file on the file system, so easy way is to simply delete the file using `java.io.File.delete()` - maybe you can catch the exception and delete the file?

Comment: As I know the realm file was stored in /data/data/packagename/files, so I cannot directly delete the file without root.

Comment: You could also try to use `Realm.deleteRealm()`.